# Unable to scrape hidden data that is shown with hovering

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

URL: https://www.nike.com/w/sale-3yaep

With the website above, what I'm trying to is scrape all products URL. BeautifulSoup will only extract the products default images. If a product has multiple colors, thus multiple product URL's, I will not be able to capture that URL information.

See below for example: top image is the default image for this product. Hovering over the image you can see different colors. If you then hover over another color the URL will change. This is the information I need to extract.

[image: Default Product Image]

[image: Hovering over a different color - URL changes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually data is also generating from api calls json response. Here is the working example:

Code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

params = {
    "queryid": "products",
    "anonymousId": "1073AB4A1C5F8BFD37D3302DFF7210E5",
    "country": "us",
    "endpoint": "/product_feed/rollup_threads/v2?filter=marketplace(US)&filter=language(en)&filter=employeePrice(true)&filter=attributeIds(5b21a62a-0503-400c-8336-3ccfbff2a684)&anchor=24&consumerChannelId=d9a5bc42-4b9c-4976-858a-f159cf99c647&count=24",
    "language": "en",
    "localizedRangeStr": "{lowestPrice} — {highestPrice}"
     }

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'}

data=[]
url= 'https://api.nike.com/cic/browse/v1'
r = requests.get(url, params=params,headers = headers)

for item in r.json()['data']['products']['products']:
    data.append([
        item['title'],
        item['subtitle'],
        item['colorDescription'],
        item['images']['portraitURL'],
        item['colorways'][0]['images']['portraitURL'],
        item['colorways'][0]['images']['squarishURL']
        ])


cols=['Product_title','Product_subtitle','Product_color','Images-01','colorways-01','colorways-02']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
print(df)
#df.to_csv('info.csv',index = False)
```

Output:

```
                   Product_title  ...                                       colorways-02
0                        Kyrie Flytrap 4  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/33c...
1                                   Nike  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/a8c...
2            Nike Sportswear Club Fleece  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/e77...
3                        Nike Sportswear  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/bcc...
4                       Nike Dri-FIT One  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/02b...
5                     Nike React Miler 2  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/261...
6                   Nike Pegasus Trail 2  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/517...
7                    Nike TechKnit Ultra  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/d6f...
8                              Nike Fast  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/c10...
9                  Nike Air Max Infinity  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/d85...
10                  Nike Free X Metcon 2  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/wo6...
11      Nike Dri-FIT Indy Rainbow Ladder  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/085...
12               Nike One Rainbow Ladder  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/662...
13                     Nike Revolution 5  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/a9d...
14                     Nike Revolution 5  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/50b...
15                       Nike Sportswear  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/258...
16                   Nike Dri-FIT Trophy  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/w1o...
17                                Jordan  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/ca9...
18                    Nike Dri-FIT Tempo  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/26e...
19                     LeBron Soldier 14  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/3a1...
20                        KD Trey 5 VIII  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/i1-...
21  Nike Sportswear Windrunner Tech Pack  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/i1-...
22         USA Nike Therma Flex Showtime  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/7e1...
23                   Nike Blazer Low '77  ...  https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_default/b97... 

[24 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: thank you. I'm trying to test this and I have a question -- where in the above script points toward the sales page? (i.e. my above URL https://www.nike.com/w/sale-3yaep) .... I want to confirm this is pulling in the correct products

Answer (score 0):

> First call URL

```
import requests
headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36"}
res=requests.get("https://www.nike.com/in/t/kyrie-flytrap-3-ep-basketball-shoe-0qb5vw/CD0191-103",headers=headers)
```

> Second use `bs4` for finding elements

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
```

> Third : you can find manually from soup just URL and it will give you
> `a` tag with class
>
> In which i have used css selector with it and after looping over it we
> can  extract `href`

```
main_data=soup.select("a.colorway-product-overlay")
for i in main_data:
    print(i['href'])
```

> Output:

```
https://www.nike.com/in/t/kyrie-flytrap-3-ep-basketball-shoe-0qb5vw/CD0191-104
https://www.nike.com/in/t/kyrie-flytrap-3-ep-basketball-shoe-0qb5vw/CD0191-103
https://www.nike.com/in/t/kyrie-flytrap-3-ep-basketball-shoe-0qb5vw/CD0191-006
https://www.nike.com/in/t/kyrie-flytrap-3-ep-basketball-shoe-0qb5vw/CD0191-100
https://www.nike.com/in/t/kyrie-flytrap-3-ep-basketball-shoe-0qb5vw/CD0191-009
```

Comment: thanks, but I need this for each product/color on the main page I provided.. not just for the individual shoe product in the picture.